# VBA for changing font and colour of a cell if a certain word is typed in it

Tags: vba, excel, fonts, colors

I have a somewhat large spreadsheet with a type of summary page that follows a calender layout.

On this page I manually change the font and color of cells to make it easy for me to find certain things on it. For example, (I lecture mathematics) if I have revision on a certain lesson, I make that cell bold and green. (exact type of green I can sort out myself). I want a VBA code if possible so that if I type the word revision into a cell on that sheet only, not whole workbook, that it would automatically change it to green.

Realistically, I don't manually type in the word revision always. Some of it uses lookups of various types to find what happens on that day to display a word (for example revision) in that given cell.

I don't know if this is possible to do. I realize that if "revision" is shown due to a lookup then the contents of that cell is not equal to "revision" but a formula which simply displays "revision"

Any assistance would be appreciated. If I have a basic code I can manipulate to get it right.

Thanks

Comment: Use conditional formatting on the range - it takes into account what is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
   Sub CheckRevision()
      Dim CurCell As Object
      For Each CurCell In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ500")
         If CurCell.Value = "Revision" Then CurCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0,204,0)
      Next
   End Sub
```

Or equivalently, you can probably use conditional formatting. Home Tab > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Text that Contains. From there, type the value "Revision" into the value box and you can change the format of the cell to how you like it.

Comment: Thanks, the conditional formatting was so simple, don't know why I forgot about it. I completely overthought that problem.